# img gallery w/o thumbnails that opens by clicking on <a>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I`'ll try to be as clear and concise as possible.

How would you do a gallery that opens **without leaving the page** by clicking on one of these list items (sort of like photobox or lightbox).

It should be something like this: you click on a list item (offices for example), and you have couple of office images to list trough. There would be no thumbnails of those viewable images, just simple "office" button, and couple of images related to it that **aren't visible to user untill he clicks on a list item and activates the album.**

```
 <li>

    <a href="#image-1">
        <img src="images/thumbs/fashionthumb.png" alt="image01">
        <span>Fashion stores </span>
    </a>
    </li>

 <li>

    <a href="#image-1">
        <img src="images/thumbs/fashionthumb.png" alt="image01">
        <span>offices </span>
    </a>
    </li>
```

If you understood my question, please recommend a jquery plugin that can suit my needs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://fancybox.net/

Also, remember to put `rel="example_group"` in all links that you want to show up in the gallery. If you place this attribute in the items, the fancybox will have a next/prev arrow to cycle through the images.

hope this helps!

Comment: This is pretty much the most commonly used and maybe the sexiest "lightbox" type plugin around at the moment.